# How do I keep an h5py group in memory after closing the file?

Tags: python, h5py

How do I keep an h5py group in memory after closing the file?

After the following code:

```
import h5py

feature_file = h5py.File(worm_file_path, 'r')
worm_features = feature_file["worm"]
```

I can access `worm_features` as it is an [h5py group](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html) (`<HDF5 group "/worm" (4 members)>`)

But after I run the line:

```
feature_file.close()
```

I can no longer access `worm_features`.  It now appears as `<Closed HDF5 group>`.

Since I need to load the worm_features h5py group for about 20 files, I'd like to close those files before doing processing on the data I've loaded into memory.  Is this not possible?

Comment: Simply defining `worm_features` does not load the group's data into memory.  You have to first assign the `.value` (or `[:]`) of all its datasets.

Comment: How are you loading and processing from just one of those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .value to pull the variable you want from the dataset.

Example:

```
import h5py

feature_file = h5py.File(worm_file_path, 'r')
worm_features = feature_file["worm"].value
feature_file.close()
print worm_features
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[:]` to copy the value of dataset to a variable to have access the dataset after closing the hdf5 file.

```
import h5py

feature_file = h5py.File(worm_file_path, 'r')
worm_features = feature_file["worm"] [:]
feature_file.close()
print (worm_features)
```

`.value` does not work for me and raised following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'
```